# Accessing files from Docker container in Finder

Tags: macos, docker

I'm exploring using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for web development on my MacBook. I've set up a couple of containers successfully, but one thing has me completely lost. How do I make the web files accessible through the Finder so can edit in BBEdit & upload to shared hosting?

In case it's relevant, I'm using a 2017 MacBook running Big Sur.

Comment: You can't make them visible in Finder. BBEdit maybe - The Docker process is in effect a different machine so look at How BBEdit does remote access e.g. ssh. An alternative is make the docker container read from the mac's file system but that might not provide the isolation that you are after.

Answer (score 5):

Mount a volume in the container from a folder on the host.

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container …
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

The path on the host will be visible in Finder and changes made in one will be reflected in the other.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Docker Desktop to "View Files". From there, you can save, edit (if the file is not read-only), delete, and import files.

[image]

This does not surface the files in the MacOS Finder, however - it shows the files in Docker's file tree GUI, but it should be familiar enough to move forward.